# Saving issue in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to save multipliable ids in the database using loop  but it only save the last id 3 times so I made for loop to test it

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i ++)
    {
        $this->product_id = $i;
        $this->shop_name  = $shop;
        $this->save();
    }
```

it saves number 9    three times  and stops ????

This issue never happened before

Comment: where do you use this code?

Comment: please paste the method, other wise can't find the solution for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a new instance with each iteration, for example:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $this->create(['product_id' => $i, 'shop_name' => $shop]);
}
```

Your code updates a single instance multiple times.